# Can't solve underfull \vbox

Tags: errors, formatting

I have searched the internet trying to find a solution to my problem; I understand there are many similar questions, but nothing has helped.

I am typesetting a novel, so it has \flushbottom, which causes underfull \vbox errors. **I believe the recommended solution is to make the pagesize a multiple of some other number so that the lines perfectly fit until the end of the page, but I cannot work out how to do this.** Could you please explain how do fix this as if I were 5 years old, as I've read many solutions but I haven't been able to grasp it.

My preamble is:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{microtype} 

\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american, maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage[paperwidth=150mm, paperheight=230mm, showframe]{geometry}
    \geometry{total={120mm, 200mm}, left=15mm, right=15mm, top=15mm, bottom=15mm}
    \geometry{nofoot}
    \geometry{nohead}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{setspace}
    \setstretch{1}

\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\frenchspacing
\flushbottom

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={NoRequired,NoCommon,NoContextual}]{Minion Pro}
```

I'm sure there are many issues/redundancies besides my main problem.

Thank you.

Comment: For text height, `geometry` accepts the key `lines= number of lines per page`. Maybe, it could solve your problem? There is also the key `height rounded`.

Comment: @Bernard The key name is `heightrounded`

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, I wrote that from memory.

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX is *very* picky on output appearance. `Underfull \vbox`means it has got a page it thinks is too empty. Look at the output, see if it is acceptable.

Most of the time, trying to force LaTeX into behaviour like `\flushbottom` is a mistake, it does fine without much meddling.